# PG::Connection is not properly escaping apostrophes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

Been trying to debug an issue with my rails app where apostrophes were being duplicated in the database.

```
[17] pry(main)> ComponentValue.new(value: "I'm O'Riley")
=> #<ComponentValue:0x007f95ca6bbd88 @value="I''m O''Riley">
```

Traced the issue back to `PG::Connection` and found that the escape method is not working properly.

```
[1] pry(main)> PG::Connection.escape("I'm O'Riley")
=> "I''m O''Riley"
```

Now I THINK that the gem is broken... But first, am I missing something?? Second, other than fixing the gem, is there anything I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: Your problem lies elsewhere. Standard SQL doubles single quotes to escape them so `escape` is working properly. What is this `ComponentValue` and why is it calling `PG::Connection.escape`?

Comment: BTW, you only need to `escape` strings that you're interpolating/concatenating into SQL strings. If you're escaping strings and then sending them to the database through other means then that's where your doubled single quotes are coming from.

Comment: Then why is it that when I run `PG::Connection.escape("I'm O'Riley")` in my terminal I'm getting `"I''m O''Riley"`

Comment: You're escaping a string and getting an escaped string back. What are you expecting `PG::Connection.escape` to do to a string? Why would `PG::Connection.escape("I'm O'Riley")` return anything other than `"I''m O''Riley"`?

Comment: Well that isn't escaping. It is duplicating. `\'` would be escaping.

Comment: Yes, that is SQL escaping as I said in my first comment. If you want to send a (Ruby) string `"O'Riley"` to the database, it needs to see `'O''Riley'` because (a) SQL uses single quotes for string literals and (b) a single quote inside a string literal is escaped by doubling it. Go to `psql` and say `select 'O''Riley';` and you'll see. Some databases will allow you to use double quotes for string literals but that's non-standard, double quotes are for quoting identifiers (such as table and column names). Every language has its own escaping rules, that's why you use library methods to do it.

Comment: What specifically are you using these strings for that you would want a single quote escaped as `\'`?